# Comments from main thread missing on api call to MR discussions

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, merge-request

I'm using the documented endpoint to get all discussions items from a Merge Request

`GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/discussions` [docs here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/discussions.html#list-project-merge-request-discussion-items)

However, in the response, I only get the comments made on the code.
For what I can see in a MR one can comment on the code, or leave comments on the MR itself.

And I don't get those last ones from the API. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Maybe the MR [notes API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html) is what you want? Also double check you are grabbing all results (by default you only get 20 per page)

Comment: Of course! I forgot the pagination.
(I thought that was the notes API! Don't I get all notes in discussion API?)
Really helpful! @sytech

Comment: Want to give the right answer?